# When does Google I/O registration open up usually?

Tags: android

I have been polishing my Java lately, and I am really starting to dig into the Android SDK. I am looking forward to attending Google's I/O conference next year, and I am nervous that I am going to miss the sign up period. Historically, when has the conference registration opened up? For those of you who went last year, do you remember when registration opened up?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/06/save-date-for-google-io-2011.html), Google will "keep you updated when registration opens for I/O 2011 on the [Google Code Blog](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/), [Twitter](http://twitter.com/googleio), and [Buzz](http://www.google.com/profiles/googleio#buzz)." According to [this](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/google-io-2010-now-open-for.html), last year it started in Jan, early bird reg ended April 16

Answer (score -1):

According to Google's official blog, I think is 1/12/2010.
Check out the link for more info of the Google I/O 2010!!!

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/google-io-2010-now-open-for.html